# c++ operator new and delete memory leak with containers

Tags: c++, list, memory, containers, memory-leaks

Seems its easy question, but I am doubt. Will operator `delete` destroy **all** `Object`'s elements when I call `delete list` for non empty list **created with operator** `new`? Sure it will, but I need confirmation. As you see `Object` have constructor, but without distributor.

Code:

```
std::list<Object>* ptr_listObjects = new std::list<Object>();
OtherObject* ptr_null = NULL;
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
ptr_listObjects->push_back ( Object( ptr_null, 'A') );
delete ptr_listObjects; // no any possible memory leaks? (Object does not use `new` operator)


class Object
{
public:
    Object( OtherObject* ptr_other, char xxx):
    ptr_OtherObject(ptr_other),
    charflag(xxx)
    {}


    OtherObject* ptr_OtherObject;
    char charflag;
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will as well. But the easiest way to handle such a situation, is to create a destructor that prints a message and see if there is any output.

Comment: I'm assuming your intent is to *not* practice the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for class `Object` in this sample. There are times when you don't need to (Object doesn't "own" the `ptr_OtherObject` object), but it is hard saying if this is one of those times. hopefully you will know (it is after all your code).

Comment: Please do check this out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::list` destructor will run and so will the destructor of it's elements. That said, why are you allocating a container dynamically to begin with?  You're making it impossible for the container to manage memory for you.  Let it do its job; allocate the list with automatic storage duration.

As an aside, `Object` *does* have a destructor, the compiler generates an empty one for you. There's nothing to clean up though, so it doesn't do anything.  Also, it is clear from the class design that instances of `Object` do not own the pointer it takes in its constructor, so make sure to never deallocate it unless you change your design significantly.

Comment: Thank you. I am allocating it dynamically, because I 1) use it at many functions and transfer it pointer through functions 2) then I store it for ~30 minutes and only that I can destroy it with operator `delete`..

Comment: @abrahab: There are other ways.  I can honestly say I have *never* dynamically allocated a container like that (and I write C++ code every day, though of course, that doesn't mean I have encountered all situations).  You can pass the container to functions by reference.  If that will not work then you should maintain it as a `unique_ptr<std::list<Object>>`. The smart pointer will deallocate it for you. There is no good reason that I can think of to do what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, I am not so good at c++ and I does not use `unique_ptr`, because I am writing at old C++ standard... Does not know how to use new features of C++ and compile at old machines such FreeBSD 6&7 where gcc seems does not know new standard...

Comment: @abrahab: It's alright, it takes time.  In writing C++ day to day I really *never* use `operator new` or `operator delete` and, if I do, it's managed by some sort of smart pointer.  You can always use boost, and you also have access to `std::auto_ptr`, though it has been deprecated for good reason.